# AIDE - Android IDE - SQLiteOpenHelper - Database

Tags: aide-ide, android-ide, aide

Can anybody help me how to create database use sqlite on android app (AIDE), i have try any source code and when i running the project, the project always force close,

Answer (score -1):

You have to have the newest version of AIDEpro. Then clone https://github.com/mobilesiri/Android-Sqlite-Database-Tutorial
It is passing the build on my android device with AIDE pro. There is also a tutorial you are looking for in the github project mentioned above.